# individual colors per circle buttons in android studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to get this working here... multiple colored circle buttons without 8 XML files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="1000dp" />
    <solid android:color="#41ba7a" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#03ae3c" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />
</shape>
```

This is my working code for making a circle button. I must ask however, if I want to create many circle buttons with different colors, do I need a new XML for each new color? Or is there a way around that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is one option you can achieve this programatically

```
 Button button2 findViewById(R.id.button2);
 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable) button2.getBackground();
            bgShape.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(CONTEXT, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }
    });
```